# How do I make shinyjs::show work with animation? Is this behaviour here a bug?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to show a datatable depending on wether a checkbox is checked or not. It is working fine if I do not animate, however with animations active it does not work. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  "Bli",
  checkboxInput("ch","Display datatable"),
  DT::DTOutput("dt"),
  "Blub"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ch,{
    if(input$ch){
      shinyjs::show("dt",
                    anim = TRUE)
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("dt")
    }
  })
  output$dt <- DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(iris))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you remove the `anim = TRUE` part, it works, with this part, there is only a bit of movement but no table visible...

Is there another workaround apart from not using animations?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. But if you want, you can use the **shinyGizmo** package. It has amazing effects for showing/hiding a conditional panel. Here is an example. Unfortunately it doesn't work if you start with an unchecked checkbox.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyGizmo)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("ch", "Display datatable", value = TRUE),
  br(), br(),
  conditionalJS(
    div(DTOutput("dt")),
    "input.ch",
    jsCalls$animateVisibility(
      effectShow = "jello",
      effectHide = "slideOutLeft",
      delay = 0,
      duration = 1500,
      ignoreInit = TRUE,
      when = TRUE
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt <- renderDT(datatable(iris))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]